# CLIPS: difference between two lists of facts

Tags: clips

If I have a bunch of facts like (example (fact 1)), (example (fact 2)), (example (fact 3)), and have another list of facts like (myfact (number 2)), how can I perform a printout on each item in the first list that is not in the second (based on the number in the fact/number slots)? I suspect I need do-for-all-facts, but I'm not sure exactly how. Here's my incomplete code:

```
(deffunction difference ()
    (do-for-all-facts ((?f1 example)) TRUE
        (find-all-facts ((?f2 myfact)) (eq 1 1))
        (if (somehow check if ?f1:fact does not equal ANY of number slots in ?f2) then
            (printout t "..." crlf))))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (deftemplate example (slot fact))
CLIPS> (deftemplate myfact (slot number))
CLIPS> 
(deffacts start
   (example (fact 1))
   (example (fact 2))
   (example (fact 3))
   (myfact (number 2))
   (myfact (number 4)))
CLIPS> 
(deffunction difference ()
   (do-for-all-facts ((?f1 example))
      (not (any-factp ((?f2 myfact)) (eq ?f1:fact ?f2:number)))
      (printout t "difference " ?f1:fact crlf)))
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (difference)
difference 1
difference 3
CLIPS> 
(defrule difference
   (example (fact ?n))
   (not (myfact (number ?n)))
   =>
   (printout t "difference " ?n crlf))
CLIPS> (run)
difference 3
difference 1
CLIPS>
```